# How to configure read-only branches in a central "development repository"?

Tags: git

I have to configure **read-only** access for some **remote branches** of a controlled git repository.

The scenario is as follows:

For our development, we have an internal "development repository" <sup>(1)</sup> that mirrors an "external repository". This "development repository" gets periodic updates (`git remote update` in a `cron` job). Our development takes place in branches "dev_*" *derived* from the external repositories, but *never direct* on the external branch:

[image: Repositories schema]

The workflow for adding functionality to `master`:

1. We create a branch `dev_master` with `master` as parent.
2. John clones the repository `development`, checks out `dev_master`, works on it, and pushes regularly back to `development`.
3. If the repository `external` gets `master` updated, so is `master` in `development` (due to the above mentioned cronjob), and someone can merge `master` on `dev_master`, so we keep in sync with `external`.

We need to forbid John's pushes to the branch `master` of `development`, so his changes doesn't get lost after the periodic update from `external`.

Again, schematic:

[image: Repositories summary]

---

#### Notes

<sup>(1)</sup> I could find that some people call this development repository "staging repository" (for example, in [How do I setup a staging repository in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7840861/413020), where a very similar situation has been presented)

Comment: Very similar to [Prohibit remote pushing to the master branch in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045329/prohibit-remote-pushing-to-the-master-branch-in-git). The difference is that I need to forbid access to all branches of the external repository, whereas in the mentioned question, the author only needed to forbid pushes to the `master` branch

Comment: See also, for the remote side, http://stackoverflow.com/a/5097437/6309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forbid these pushes using a [Server-Side hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks). From `git help hooks`:

> **pre-receive**
>   This hook is invoked by git-receive-pack on the remote repository, which happens when
>   a git push is done on a local repository. Just before starting to update refs on the
>   remote repository, the pre-receive hook is invoked. Its exit status determines the
>   success or failure of the update.
>    [...]
>    If the hook exits with non-zero status, none of the refs will be updated. If the hook
>   exits with zero, updating of individual refs can still be prevented by the update
>   hook.
>   [...]

The hook code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Read the branches of the remote repository
remote_branches=$(git ls-remote --heads | sed "s,.*\(refs/heads/\),\1,")

function forbid_push_to_remote_branches()
{
    while read old_value new_value ref_name
    do
        # Test for existence of [$ref_name] in remote
        for remote_branch in $remote_branches
        do
            if [[ $remote_branch == $ref_name ]]
            then
                invalid_refs="$invalid_refs [$remote_branch]"
                break
            fi
        done
    done

    # if remote read-only branches found, exit with non-zero
    # and list these branches
    if [[ -n $invalid_refs ]]
    then
        echo "ERROR: You are trying to push to remote branch(es):" >&2
        echo "   $invalid_refs" >&2
        return 1 
    else
        return 0
    fi
}

forbid_push_to_remote_branches
exit $?
```

This code must be copied to the file `$(bare_repo_path.git)/hooks/pre-receive` in the server (there is no `pre-receive.sample`).