# How to disable version control in phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I am playing around with phpstorm and somehow I activated version control. I don't need it. Now all my tabs are different: orange text on gray background. All files in the file view are orange. How do I disable version control?

Comment: **Settings | Version Control** -- remove all entries from the table.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Version Control and remove the folder from which you would like to remove version control tracking (coloring tabs etc.) It will naturally **not** remove version control from your project (as in deleting the .git/ folder for instance).

Comment: All that does is make them unregistered roots, now I get notices for unregistered roots.

Comment: This works for version 2017.1.2 too. Additionally to remove 'unregistered roots' notification, go to Application & Behaviour -> Notifications and uncheck 'Vcs Notifications'. Now it's all happy.

Answer (score 13):

The ultimate way is to disable all version control plugins (under `Settings -> Plugins`): CVS Integration, Git Integration, GitHub, hg4idea, Perforce Integration, Subversion Integration. After restarting PhpStorm `Settings -> Version Control` tab will be gone.

Note that this will disable version control for all of your projects.

Comment: Nice, thank you. This is the answer if you use another program for version contral and don't want your IDE getting in the way.

Answer (score 7):

You can just remove `vcs.xml` from **`.idea`** folder and then restart PhpStorm

Comment: This should NOT be marked as the correct answer. Any time PhpStorm is restarted, it will re-generate vcs.xml and the problem instantly reappears. You must de-register the project from within PhpStorm by going to Settings > Version Control and removing the project from the list, as others have said.

Comment: @weivall is not the answer, please uncheck.

Comment: It was working for me in PhpStorm 7. I can't give any guarantee for the new versions.

Answer (score 3):

In phpStorm 2022.1.3+, go to

```
Preferences > Version Control > Directory Mappings
```

Then remove the directories you don't want to watch, as Greg suggested.

Answer (score 1):

> Go to Settings -> Version Control and remove the folder from which you would liek to remove version control.

I have not enough reputation to +1 Greg's answer or comment, but... for those who are interrested : the same goes for **Webstorm**.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I used from 2 of notes in these answers in these page together.

As Greg has mentioned in one of replies, your git repository is in `.git` sub directory inside directory that you want to manage it with version control system. When you define a git repository, PhpStorm automatically generate it and with creating this sub directory, it adds a file for handling mapping between itself and version control system. It calls `vcs.xml` and it's located in `.idea` sub directory.

It's not enough to remove only `.git` directory. When you remove `.git`, you will get an error in PhpStorm every time that you open your project due to not matching  `vcs.xml` for mapping between PhpStorm and git repository of your project. So after removing `.git` directory, you must also remove `vcs.xml` files from .`idea` and now you won't have any error or warning in your PhpStorm.

It doesn't need to restart PhpStorm at all and after this, colors of all of files that was mentioned in questions return to normal colors in PhpStorm.

Comment: There is an answer in here somewhere, but it needs a little editing. Try to break up this wall of text so it has a beginning, a middle, and an end.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully remove all VCS related settings.

**Step 1** 

Go to `Setting > Version Control > Directory Mappings` 
Select your folder there and remove it.

[image: Directory Mappings]

**Step 2** 

Go to your project folder, using your windows/mac/linux file browser. 
In that folder, you should have a `.git` folder. Delete it. 
*If you don't see the folder, make sure you can see hidden items. (On windows, in your file browser: view > hidden items)*

**Step 3** 

Restart the IDE 
*You can also hide the version control tab from your main IDE window by right clicking the version control tab and selecting `Remove from Sidebar`*

**To confirm that it worked**
Go to the VCS drop-down, you should see `Enable Version Control Integration ...`